# “every" will change the shape in TikZ in LaTeX?

Tags: tikz-pgf, shapes

I am read the **TikZ** pdf file, in which there sometime use `every` to define a style, but sometimes not. After comparing `every` or no `every`, I found there is a change of shapes. For example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta,petri,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance=1.3cm,on grid,>={Stealth[round]},bend angle=45,auto,
every place/.style= {minimum size=6mm,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20},
every transition/.style={thick,draw=black!75,fill=black!20},
red place/.style= {place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20},
every label/.style= {red}]
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta,petri,positioning}
\node [place,tokens=1] (w1) {};
\node [place] (c1) [below=of w1] {};
\node [place] (s) [below=of c1,label=above:$s\le 3$] {};
\node [place] (c2) [below=of s] {};
\node [place,tokens=1] (w2) [below=of c2] {};
\node [transition] (e1) [left=of c1] {}
edge [pre,bend left] (w1)
edge [post,bend right] (s)
edge [post] (c1);
\node [transition] (e2) [left=of c2] {}
edge [pre,bend right] (w2)
edge [post,bend left] (s)
edge [post] (c2);
\node [transition] (l1) [right=of c1] {}
edge [pre] (c1)
edge [pre,bend left] (s)
edge [post,bend right] node[swap] {2} (w1);
\node [transition] (l2) [right=of c2] {}
edge [pre] (c2)
edge [pre,bend right] (s)
edge [post,bend left] node {2} (w2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
[node distance=1.3cm,on grid,>={Stealth[round]},bend angle=45,auto,
place/.style= {minimum size=6mm,thick,draw=blue!75,fill=blue!20},
transition/.style={thick,draw=black!75,fill=black!20},
red place/.style= {place,draw=red!75,fill=red!20},
every label/.style= {red}]
\usetikzlibrary {arrows.meta,petri,positioning}
\node [place,tokens=1] (w1) {};
\node [place] (c1) [below=of w1] {};
\node [place] (s) [below=of c1,label=above:$s\le 3$] {};
\node [place] (c2) [below=of s] {};
\node [place,tokens=1] (w2) [below=of c2] {};
\node [transition] (e1) [left=of c1] {}
edge [pre,bend left] (w1)
edge [post,bend right] (s)
edge [post] (c1);
\node [transition] (e2) [left=of c2] {}
edge [pre,bend right] (w2)
edge [post,bend left] (s)
edge [post] (c2);
\node [transition] (l1) [right=of c1] {}
edge [pre] (c1)
edge [pre,bend left] (s)
edge [post,bend right] node[swap] {2} (w1);
\node [transition] (l2) [right=of c2] {}
edge [pre] (c2)
edge [pre,bend right] (s)
edge [post,bend left] node {2} (w2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Outputs:

[image]

It is weird, as no `every` causes circles to squares.

Comment: By saying `place/.style={...}` you overwrote the definition of `place` from the `petri` library which includes the `circle` shape: https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/blob/3.1.10/tex/generic/pgf/frontendlayer/tikz/libraries/tikzlibrarypetri.code.tex#L16-L18

Comment: @HenriMenke Why did it change to squares, not rectangle or others?

Comment: @Y.zeng A rectangle is just the default. They look square because you've used `minimum size` which affects height and width and there's nothing else to make one larger than the other (no content). Try `place/.append style=...`.